# How not to be confused for a 3rd party ad provider by ad blockers

Tags: javascript

In creating a a 3rd party service for A/B testing and behavioral targeting I have reviewed a number of similar 3rd party script tags and see so many different methods that I can't help but wonder if there is an established pattern to follow, or if you should just put a  tag and call it good.

Is there an established pattern to follow?

Comment: "confused for a 3rd party ad provider" ... "behavioral targeting" - sounds like you're doing ads.

Comment: W're modifying the user experience based on known data points. We look at where you came from, what you're doing, and your browsing patterns and use that information to infer your digital intent. We use that information to shape your browsing experience. It has nothing to do with ads at all.